# How do I make "black&white" the default?

Tags: printing, cups

When I print something (Firefox 5 but also other apps), the option "color" is always set to "Color (CMYK)". How do I make "monochrome" or "black & white" the default?

This is a [Kyocera FS-C5100DN](http://www.kyoceramita.eu/index/products/product/fsc5100dn.html) with CUPS 1.4.6-5ubuntu1.3.

**[EDIT]** Output of `lpstat -d -v`:

```
system default destination: FS-C5100DN
device for FS-C5100DN: socket://192.168.0.24
```

So the question is now: Can I change the default somehow on my own computer without changing settings on the server?

Comment: Can someone with enough points please add "black&white" or "monochrome" or "B&W" or some similar tag?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. Also the [tag:colors] tag you used is actually for something else in Unix. The [tag:cups] tag is the right one to use for this.

Comment: Please show the output of `lpstat -d -v`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385997/cups-how-to-enforce-bw-printing-for-a-queue

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can configure CUPS defaults for your account by running the [`lpoptions`](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.5/man-lpoptions.html) command. Run `lpoptions -l` to see what options are available for your printer, and determine which one corresponds to the color/monochrome choice. For example, with this output

```
$ lpoptions -l | grep Color
ColorModel/Color Model: Gray Black *RGB CMY CMYK KCMY
```

I would set `ColorModel` to `Black`. Then run `lpoptions -o NAME=VALUE` to set a default option. This creates a file called `~/.cups/lpoptions` that applications using CUPS will read.

```
lpoptions -o ColorModel=Black
```

Other printers may use different parameters, e.g.

```
lpoptions -o ColorType=Mono
```

You can define aliases for sets of options and make one of them the default.

```
lpoptions -p FS-C5100DN/bw -o ColorModel=Black
lpoptions -p FS-C5100DN/color -o ColorModel=RGB
lpoptions -d FS-C5100DN/bw
```

Comment: Note: `Color` is not a standard option. On my Epson XP-202 it was `Ink=MONO`, to you really have to `| less` it up and read in general :-(

Comment: sometimes lpoptions is not working in osx, I had to use lpadmin -p <printername> -o ColorMode=mono for a Canon Printer with OSX 10.11.6

Answer (score 2):

Most CUPS printer drivers have this in their options settings. I don't know about Ubunutu but a default CUPS installation will include a special local-host only web server that can be used for configuration and management of printers. Try this URL: http://127.0.0.1:631

From there go to the Printers tab, select the printer you want to modify, then choose "Set Defaults Options" from the Administration menu. My printer has B&W default options under the Printout Mode tab, but yours may vary.

Comment: The "Printers" tab is empty :-/ Which is odd because I can print (just did it :-) ) `lpq` can see my printer. My guess is that this is a remote queue. Any idea where I should look for it?