# How to force lp from CUPS to print in grayscale?

Tags: colors, printing, cups, images

I want to print an image from a command line:

```
lp -o scaling=//100// image.jpg
```

How can I force it to be printed in grayscale?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18449/77539

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [`lpoptions`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_lpoptions.htm) ?

Use `lpoptions -l` in order to know what's the name for your printer.

You can play it like thi (example with an HP Photosmart) :

```
lp -o scaling=//100// -oColorModel=KGray image.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the PPD file for the current printer, you should get a hint of how to denote grayscale printing (or any option for that matter). It could be as above or `ColorModel=Gray`, `ColorModel=Grayscale`, etc.

Try the following command to search the options for printers on your system:

```
grep -i gr[ae]y /etc/cups/ppd/*.ppd
```

Answer (score 1):

Open cups window in Raspberry pi os

```
menu > preferences > Print Settings > select your printer > Properties >

Printer Options > Color Model > Grayscale
```

Comment: The question is not about Raspberry.

Comment: But as raspberry is Linux based. So the options would be same, I hope.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to convert the image to a grayscale version, by e.g GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick.

Comment: Could you add a solution? Maybe the command to run to convert an image to greyscale.

Comment: @n0pe, try: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13317753